# VS Code terminal changed to interactive terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Recently, I started working on webd, so to run the HTML, CSS and Javascript, I made few changes randomly from youtube which I don't remember. From then my VS Code terminal which I generally use to run C++ has changed its settings. My code is not taking whole input in a single time as it used to do earlier, so I again saw youtube and made changes, deleted default json code. By hook and crook I made the VS Code to run in interactive mode, but I actually want it to take whole input at a time. What changes should I make?

`if ($?) { g++ w.cpp -o w } ; if ($?) { .\w }`

Earlier I didn't get these lines in my terminal

Just suggest me how I can make my VS Code terminal to take whole input at a time and give out whole output at time.

Comment: `terminal to take whole input` what do you mean by this

Comment: that line is the compile-and-run command for C++ files